# Accessing class properties and protected classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is part of my homework. I am creating a Shipyard simulator. The Shipyard consists of containers (that are linked list) and inside those containers are packages (that are also a collection of linked list). The containers have the following properties (Destination, weightlimit, ID) and parcels have(name of owner, destination, weight, ID) Basically, when I create a new Package, if a container with the same destination does not exist, then I need to create a new container inside the shipyard and place the package within the container; otherwise I will just place the package in the corresponding container. Containers are ordered alphabetically and packages are ordered lightest first.

This is what I have so far. I wrote the add_container() for testing and it works but I won't need it; the real job is done by the add() method. It is not working and I can't figure out why. If any of you can give me a reason or even a hint, I would really appreciate it.

```
from random import *

#Package class

class Package:

    def __int__(self, name, destination, weight):
        self._name = name
        self._destination = destination
        self._weight = weight
        self._Next = None
        self._ID = 0

#Container Class
class Container:

    def __init__(self, dest):
        self._dest = dest
        self._Front = None
        self._next = None
        self._Maxweight = 2000
        self._size = 0
        self._Identification = 0


class Shipyard:

    def __init__(self):
        self._Front = None
        self._size = 0



    def size(self):
        return self._size



    def add_container(self, Destination):

        container = Container(Destination)

        if self._Front == None:
            self._Front = container
            self._size += 1
            container._Identification = ((randint(1,1999)))

        elif container._dest < self._Front._dest:
            container._next  = self._Front
            self._Front = container
            self._size += 1
            container._Identification = ((randint(1, 1999)))

        else:

            current = self._Front
            previous = None

            while current is not None and current._dest < Destination:
                previous = current
                current = current._next

                if current == None:
                    previous._next = container
                    self._size += 1
                    container._Identification = ((randint(1, 1999)))

                else:
                    container._next = current
                    previous._next = container
                    self._size += 1
                    container._Identification = ((randint(1, 1999)))



    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0



    def  container_exists(self, dest):
        container_found = False
        First_container = self._Front

        if First_container == None:
            pass

        else:

            while container_found != True:
                previous = First_container
                First_container = First_container._next

                if previous._dest == dest:
                    container_found = True
                    return True

                else:

                    return False




    def printAll(self):

        current = self._Front
        while current != None:
            print(current._dest)
            current = current._next



    def add(self, name, destination, weight):

        package = Package(name, destination, weight)

        if self.container_exists(destination) == True:
            current = self._Front

            while current._dest != destination:
                current = current._next


                if current._dest == destination:

                    weightlimit = current._Maxtwiehgt - weight

                    if weightlimit <= 0:
                        print("Container to ", destination, "is full!")
                        return

                    if current._Front == None:
                        current._Front = package
                        current._Maxtweihgt -= weight
                        current._size += 1
                        current._Front._ID = (randint(1,1999))

                    else:
                        currentPackage = current._Front
                        previousPackage = None

                        while currentPackage._Next!= None:

                            previousPackage = currentPackage
                            currentPackage = currentPackage._Next

                            if currentPackage._weight > weight > previousPackage:
                                package._Next = currentPackage
                                previousPackage._Next = package
                                package._ID = (randint(1,1999))
                                current._Maxweight -= weight
                                current._size += 1


        else:
            container = Container(destination)

            if self._Front == None:
                self._Front = container
                self._Front._Front = package #new package
                self._Front._Identification = (randint(1,1999)) #container ID
                self._Front._Maxweight -= weight #container weight
                self._Front._Front._ID = (randint(1,1999)) #package id
                self._size += 1  #shipyard size
                self._Front._size += 1 #container size


            elif self._Front._dest > destination:
                container._next = self._Front
                self._Front = container
                self._Front._Front = package  # new package
                self._Front._Identification = (randint(1, 1999))  # container ID
                self._Front._Maxweight -= weight  # container weight
                self._Front._Front._ID = (randint(1, 1999))  # package id
                self._size += 1  # shipyard size
                self._Front._size += 1  # container size


            else:
                current = self._Front
                previous = None

                while current._next != None:
                    previous = current
                    current = current._next

                    if current._dest > destination > previous._dest:
                        container._next = current
                        previous._next = container
                        container._Front = package
                        container._Identification = (randint(1,1999))
                        container._Maxweight -= weight
                        container._Front._ID = (randint(1,1999))
                        self._size += 1
                        container._size += 1




def main():

    myYard = Shipyard()
    myYard.add("Jamie", "Atlanta", 120)
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm Sorry. I am new here and completely stuck with the problem. My question is that I need to know why the program crashes and says the Package class does not take arguements

Comment: Please do not be sorry.  There are many people here who very much want to help you.  But you need to help us help you.  That means pare down your problem a bit.  What often happens if you do this is you will find the answer yourself.  And if you do not find the answer, then a pared down problem will often be answered quite quickly.

Comment: @StephenRauch thank you for clarifying that Stephen. Well my question is that I need to know why the program crashes and says the Package class does not take arguments

Comment: Please go read the links I gave.  You need to trim down what you posted here to maximize your chances of getting a quick response.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't describe the problem in any useful way.  Paraphrasing the error message is better.  Really, you should [edit] your question to include the _complete_ stacktrace and all error messages.  Python's errors are very good, and often tell you the exact line that's wrong.

Comment: For general debugging advice (including advice on asking questions about bugs), I highly recommend Eric Lippert's article, "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Answer (score 0):

Write this down: the error you are seeing is:

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

When you see `object() takes no parameters`, it almost always means you have screwed up the constructor.

First, check the number of underscores. Make sure there are two underscores in front, two in back.

Next, make sure you have spelled `__init__` correctly. For example, if you were to declare a function called `__int__` it would not do what you hope. :)